# Any Way to Further Customize Embedded Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'd like to embed a few Google Calendars for my client's web site.  The "Google Embeddable Calendar Helper" provides very few customization options.  Updating the hex code for the background color in the generated  source only works if you pick one of the ~70 standard Google Calendar bg colors.  (I *can* tweak the "border" selector because at least it's in an actual  statement.)

A "view-source" on the rendered page shows a CSS file loaded from the iframe, but I obviously can't change anything in there.  And I assume I can't force an override of selectors with my own CSS file because I have no way of "injecting" it into the iframe.

Does anyone know of a (non-API) way of tweaking the colors, fonts, and other CSS thingies in an embedded Google Calendar?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't modify the iframe because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); browsers have tightened the security on Cross frame Dom scripting due to possible hacks.
Look at [this](http://polisick.com/crossdomainformattempt.php) example.

Comment: As I said, I already know I can't inject anything into the iframe.  I guess I was hoping there's some way to apply styles and/or override selector values.  I understand the security risk associated with allowing changes to a "remote DOM tree", but I wonder if there's a way (Javascript?) to walk the tree, copy it locally, make some alterations, then re-render it.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you're hoping to avoid the complexity of an API-based approach, these days there are a number of third party apps that make it easy to style and embed Google calendars.

Here is a short list of options:

- [Styled Calendar](https://styledcalendar.com/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=forum-posts)
- [Tockify](https://tockify.com/i/docs/howto/googlesync)
- [ChronoFlo Calendar](https://www.chronoflocalendar.com/tutorials/entry/make-a-branded-version-of-your-google-calendar/)

Or, if you'd rather use something open source, [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) is a great solution. Here is some documentation on how to use their Google Calendar plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

**Full disclosure, I'm a member of the [Styled Calendar](https://styledcalendar.com/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=forum-posts) team*

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to pipe the RSS or XML feed that google provide on their calenders then reformat that into a calendar again!